# Small web-framework like Sinatra, Ramaze etc in .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, frameworks, sinatra

Are there any similar frameworks like Sinatra, Ramaze etc in .NET?

I'm in theory after a framework that let's me create an entire webapp with just one classfile (conceptually) like Sinatra.

I'm going to use it for something work-internal, where ASP.NET MVC is too "big" (and I get confused by it's usage) and I have WebForms up to my ears right now (doing a big webforms based project, currently hating it ;) )

Any suggestions?

Oh, and I need to be able to host it in IIS.
I would go for IronRuby with Sinatra, but I can't find a step-by-step tut for setting it up in IIS ;)

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a pretty small framework. Not as small as Sinatra, but nowhere near as heavyweight as WebForms.

Comment: Well, yes... But having "learned" MVC and small frameworks from Rubyland, the way ASP.NET MVC does things confuses me. It's probably my head that translates poorly from ruby to c#. So ASP.NET MVC probably isn't the problem :)

Comment: <del>Have you looked at [Kayak](http://kayakhttp.com/start)? </del> <del>It's probably the closest thing to a C# version of Sinatra I've seen out there... However it runs as it's own webserver so there's no IIS integration there.</del> Edit: Seems this project is dead, its moved to github now but hasn't been touched in a year: https://github.com/kayak/kayak

Comment: related link @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418986/is-there-a-net-framework-similar-to-rubys-sinatra

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just discovered Nancy: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.

This is an introduction from the author blog: http://elegantcode.com/2010/11/28/introducing-nancy-a-lightweight-web-framework-inspired-by-sinatra/

Comment: Ditto I asked a similar question and that was what someone suggested a long time after I asked the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418986/is-there-a-net-framework-similar-to-rubys-sinatra

Comment: I definitely recommend checking out Nancy if you are looking at something like Sinatra for .NET

Answer (score 7):

- [SharpLight](http://sharplight.codeplex.com/) (F# only)
- [Bistro](http://bistroframework.org) (especially small controllers when [used in F#](http://bistroframework.org/index.php?title=FSharp))
- [Figment](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/08/figment-web-dsl-for-f.html) (F# only)
- [Frank](http://github.com/panesofglass/frank) (F# only)
- [Suave](http://github.com/ademar/suave) (F# only)

Answer (score 2):

[N2CMS](http://www.n2cms.com) provides a framework for building websites a bit like Ramaze. It makes use of Castle, NHibernate, jQuery.

It gives you an editing interface which I'm not sure the ruby frameworks you mentioned have. An example with your ASP.NET page would be:

```
public class MyPage : ContentItem
{
    public virtual string Text
    {
        get { return GetDetail<string>("Text",""); }
        set { SetDetail("Text",value); }
    }
}
```

Your text property then is editable with a few extra additions to the web.config. It comes with a tonne of ASP.NET server controls too, to speed up development.

The latest beta version is written around ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

NicoGranelli mentioned Nancy(http://nancyfx.org/). It's really great! Plz check this project JabbR(https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR) It's a chat involving SignalR and Nancy. 
Great Job!