# How to write simple REST based server in C# on mono?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm porting a small server from Scala to C# (on Mono) and need to get a very simple REST interface going. Am trying to figure out the easiest (but robust) way to do this.

For reasons I wont go into, NOT using webservers like Apache, Nginx etc would be preferred. 
Yes, I could manually code up something listening to sockets, parse HTTP request coming in, handle threading etc... but hoping there are libraries or frameworks that already handle this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I've built a webserver that should work in mono. At least version 1.1 should.

You can find it here: http://webserver.codeplex.com.

It's not a standalone server, you include it in your project and create a webserver in you code. It support all HTTP verbs and got a small MVC framework which makes it easy to create REST services.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [manos](https://github.com/jacksonh/manos). It's a standalone high performance web application framework which, I think, can be used as a REST based server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MonoRail or [Mono WCF](http://veritas-vos-liberabit.com/monogatari/2009/12/mono-wcf-advent-day-9-restful-webhttpbinding.html).

Comment: I thought using WCF meant I still had to use another server (IIS, Apache, Nginx etc?). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I asked a question about C# options similar to Ruby's Sinatra see [Is there a .NET framework similar to Ruby's Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418986/is-there-a-net-framework-similar-to-rubys-sinatra)

Answer (score 2):

Check out Nancy - it's a lightweight web framework for .net

http://nancyfx.org/

Comment: You might want to know, that StackOverflow Netiquette encourages high quality posts and as such, you shall rather post you answer with all relevant and important details instead of just a link-only derrogations. Kindly update your post to show your will to comply with the Community rules and also to provide a persistent content of your answer for such cases, when the referred URL content becomes un-retrievable in some future re-organisation et al